# Specify depth > 1 with @Query in Spring-Data-Neo4j Repository

Tags: spring-data-neo4j-4

Using a spring-data-neo4j repository, can I use a @Query and load nodes with a depth greater than 1?

**My example is**

```
@Query("match (m:NodeTypeA)-[r:REL1]-(n:NodeTypeB {nodeBUniqueProperty: {0}}) return m")
    public NodeTypeA findByNodeBUniqueProperty(String uniqueProperty);
```

Using this query, NodeTypeA is returned. However I also want NodeTypeA's neighbours.

I can @Inject the ogm session and use that to get the results I want, however it would be nicer to do it with @Query.

I notice there is a note in the docs to say:

> In the current version, derived finders do not support paging, sorting
>   or a custom depth

but is a method using @Query a derived finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same applies to @Query. Using the Session methods (with Filters if required) would be the way to go at the moment.

Comment: Do you know what the depth is set to for these queries?

Comment: Seems like @Query has default depth=0, not 1, since nearest neighbours are not loaded (for me it is so). Is it true? Or this is my local issue?